# How can I use MooseX::ClassAttribute within a role?

Tags: perl, moose

I would like to use 
[MooseX::ClassAttribute](http://search.cpan.org/dist/MooseX-ClassAttribute) in
a role.  I.e., do something like

```
package Cachable;

use Moose::Role;
use MooseX::ClassAttribute;

class_has Cache => ( is => 'rw' );

1;
```

Unfortunately, the code above doesn't work as 
the deep magic of MooseX::ClassAttribute expects 
to be called from within a Moose object, and not a Moose::Role.
Is there any way to work around this, or is this a known limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You send me a patch that makes this work. It's certainly doable, although the Moose internals make it harder than it needs to be because of how roles handle attributes.

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess it's time for me to take a look at Moose's meta-goodness.

Comment: Was there ever an update to this? I know I have run into the same limitation.

Comment: @Dave: it would be helpful to have this limitation explicitly noted in the documentation.